# Rendering resetting bones?

Tags: armature, bones

I'm trying to pose a set of bones for a character, but whenever I go to render the scene, all the bones reset. Once I exit out of render mode, the bones are still reset. I thought this had something to do with Blender not rendering armatures, but when I found a script to make the armature a mesh model, it would still reset.

Lets's say I move this arm here.
[image]

Trying to render
[image]

And... the bones reset.
[image]

Help?

[image]

Comment: Please show the timeline with the keyframes for the armature present in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have keyframed all bones.

Armature Pose Mode 3D View Window On Frame 123 (From your pic)

Select all

<kbd>A</kbd>

Insert Keyframes

<kbd>I</kbd>

Rotation.  Scale.  From the popup menu.

Render on the same frame 123

---

Please show the timeline with the keyframes present in your original question.